# Increment a variable within *ngFor based on *ngIf evaluation

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a list of strings of which I want to display a subset as a numbered list. I managed to use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` to display the items I want, but I am struggling with the numbering.

This is the list:

```ts
let fieldnames: string[] = ["Name", "Age", "Email", "Address", "Phone"];
```

I have an object mapping the fieldnames to booleans:

```ts
let valid: { [key: string]: boolean } = {
  "Name": true,
  "Age": false,
  "Email": true,
  "Address": true,
  "Phone": false,
};
```

This is my HTML template:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let fieldname of fieldnames; let i = index">
  <div  *ngIf="valid[fieldname] === false">
    {{ i + 1 }}. {{ fieldname }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Current Output**

```
2. Age
5. Phone
```

The index increments based on the for loop, independently of the condition, so the numbering of each item corresponds to its position in the list.

**Desired Output**

```
1. Age
2. Phone
```

I only want the items numbered which are actually displayed. Is there a way to increment a variable conditionally based on the evaluation of my `*ngIf` statement?

I considered writing a separate function that returns only the sublist of fieldNames for which the condition is true. I could then loop over the sublist and use the normal index. This doesn't seem very elegant though, is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't u select only the valid ones with "map" into "valid" variable and don't have to struggle with *ngIf="valid[fieldname] === false"